# participants tied with Organization Hyperledger Composer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I wanted to understand how are participants tied with Organization when we define the model.
For example if I have `3 participants(Grower, Shipper, Trader)` and have a network of `3 organization(OrgGrower,OrgShipper, OrgTrader)`
then will adding participants how is the one to one relationship mapped between Participants and Organization.
I want to do all this via Web site and give access to administrator for adding only there participants and but also want to 
have a super admin which has access to all the organization. Is this achievable via Hyperledger composer

Answer (score 2):

Answered same posting on Rocket Chat:

In Composer a Participant is just a data item, specifically an object in a Participant Registry. A Participant cannot access the Business Network on the Fabric until an Identity has been Issued to and bound to that Participant. Identities are generated by the CA which belongs to an Organisation. A user (administrator) with an Identity can create Participants if they have the ACL access to do so, but only an Identity with specific rights in the CA can issue Identities. This doc describes Participants and Identities in more detail: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer//managing/participantsandidentities
I don't know if CAs can 'cross certify' to allow your Super Admin to issue identities for the 3 CAs (Organizations). There is a #fabric-ca channel that should be able to answer that question.

Comment: Hi this was not part of the original poster question but, If Identity are issued by CA belonging to an organization a issuer from an separate organization can use there CA to issue an end identity for that participant? And if thats the case can one limit the issuing of identity for participant on organization criteria.